# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - two header links give me that error

Tags: php

on my index.php file I have two redirects:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['email']) and isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
$url = "loginjava.php";
header( "Location: $url" );
}

else {

if(!isset($_SESSION['uniquekey'])) {
header("Location:welcome.php");
}   
}
```

The first one checks if a cookie exists. If so, it directs the user to the loginjava.php.

But if the user is logged-in to the site and did not set a cookie I need to send him to the welcome.php aswell.

But sadly I get the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and the site doesn´t load. Can someone explain this to me, please.

Thank you

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Comment: I have no .htaccess-file in my root directory. I use dreamweaver and have "show hidden files" on. What should I look for if I wanna generate one? What do I need to write in there?

Comment: Are there redirects in loginjava.php or welcome.php ? These might create a sort of redirect loop which triggers the error.

Comment: Yes, you were right philip and thanks to Sandu Andrei Luis. I overlooked a loop between the welcome.php and index.php. 
Thank you for your help